# Rails 3, add radio button with migration, how set a default to existing data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, radio-button, erb

We used a migration to add a new field to our Posts table called new_choice:integer with :default => 1

On the edit form we made it a radio button with 3 choices A,B,C represented by values 1,2,3

When a NEW record is created, the "A" button will be selected by default.

However, when an already-existing record is edited, the current value is nil so NO radio button is selected.

Is there a way to have the erb form check a particular button (A/1) if the field value sis not the "valid" choices of 1,2,3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
<%= f.radio_button :post, choice, :checked => @post.choice == choice ? true : false %>
```

Comment: that looks close... I think I need to tweak that, I dont think it handles the case I want which is IF the field value is nil then I need to choose one to be checked, otherwise the buttons matching the current value is checked (which happens automatically)... probably something like :checked => (pseudo code: true if field is nil OR if field = value, else false)

Answer (score 1):

The last option in radio button method will set the default, selected value:

```
radio_button("post", "new_choice", "1")
```